# A peculiar issue with css links

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have this CSS code for links on my site:

```
a { text-decoration:none; color:#2B5384; }
a:hover { color:#F90; }
a:visited { color:#2B5384; }
```

It works fine if the link looks like that: `<a href="mypage.html">My page</a>` - the color of the link is dark blue, on hover it changes to orange and the underline appears.
However, if I link to external website, for example `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mypage">My page</a>` - on hover the link doesn't change the color and no underline appears. It works if I change the URL to have the .html extension - `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mypage.html">My page</a>`, but, obviously, there's no such page.

Why is it happening and how can that be fixed?

Comment: Try changing order for `:hover` and `:visited` so that `:hover` is your last selector.

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos Yes, that solved it! Thank you very much! Can you please post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Steve Atkinson was quicker but I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp especially the notes :

> Note: a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS
>   definition in order to be effective!!
>
> Note: a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order
>   to be effective!!
>
> Note: Pseudo-class names are not case-sensitive.

Here's the official w3c take on it http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html see section 5.11.3